# How would I use two variables in a class with function requiring two variables?

Tags: python, class, object, methods

So I got a program consisting of a class and three methods. These three methods are three different numerical approximations of the derivative of a function. Now I have implemented a function f,x values and h values that are needed in the functions. As I am to plot these, I get nothing in the graph. Also when I print the different instances, I just get an array of the three same values

```
[5.87785252 5.87785252 5.87785252]
```

I don't know if there is something inherently wrong with the class, or if I am missing out somewhere in the code, but could someone please help me with this?

My full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Diff:
    #constructor taking f as an argument
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.f=f
        
    #method for first approximation
    def diff1(self,x,h):
        self.f=f
        self.x=x
        self.h=float(h)
        return (f(x+h)-f(x))/h
    
    #method for second approximation
    def diff2(self,x,h):
        self.f=f
        self.x=x
        self.h=float(h)
        return (f(x+h)-f(x-h))/2*h
    
    #method for third approximation
    def diff3(self,x,h):
        self.f=f
        self.x=x
        self.h=float(h)
        return (-f(x+2*h)-8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/12*h
    
    
h=[0.9,0.6,0.3,0.1]
x=np.linspace(-1,1,3)

def f(x):
    return np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

Derivative=Diff(f)
Exact=2*np.pi*np.cos(2*np.pi*x)

for h in h:
    Derivative1=Derivative.diff1(x,h)

plt.plot(Derivative1,Exact)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `self.f=f`, wasn't it meant `f=self.f`?

Comment: nope this is correct syntax

Comment: ```self.f=f``` should only be in the ```__init__``` method

Comment: Oh yes that is true, I saw just th first one.

Comment: Its risky to use a single name for multiple things. In `self.f=f`, that `f` is the `def f()` function you defined, not necessarily the `f` passed in the initializer. Rename that function to, say, `def sin_func(x)` and your program will stop working.

Comment: In your for loop `Derivative1` is overwritten with every iteration, so you only get the last value.

Comment: how do i fix that @Wups

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying to calculate so many digits after the floating point and the variable itself confuses and displays a whole different value.

you should use these variables to solve the problem:

```
np.double(num) #for 15 digit floating point presicion 
np.longdouble(num) #for 18 digit floating point precision
```

you can also use the following function to round your variable

```
np.round(num,d) #where d is the number of floating point digits left after rounding
```

another side note, you shouldn't use the same variable as your list to iterate over it, it will be a source of confusion later on
instead of:

```
for h in h:
    Derivative1=Derivative.diff1(x,h)
```

use:

```
for point in h:
    Derivative1=Derivative.diff1(x,point)
```

Comment: Wrong. I still get [5.87785252 5.87785252 5.87785252] as my print

Comment: The reason why you dont see the plot correcly is because of the floating point precision. I recommend you to print all 3 values of Derivation1 individualy. you will notice that the actual values are: 5.877852522924731,5.877852522924731,5.877852522924738 and are the actual results from your diff function

Answer (score 0):

## The Problem

I tinkert a little bit around with your code and following issue result in just three
values:

`x = np.linspace(-1,1,3)`

If you look in the documentation of linspace (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) you will see two positional arguments (`start`, `stop`) and the next optional Argument is number of steps. With your code your result of the linspace is just `[-1, 0, 1]`. This is not something linspace is needed for, but it works.

## Looping over h

instead of saving your values everytime in the same variable you could save them into an array. Something like this:

```py
Derivative1 = np.zeros((len(h), len(x)))

for idx, value in enumerate(h):
    Derivative1[idx]=Derivative.diff1(x,value)
```

Afterwards you need to check your plot function because exact and this array aren't matching anymore.